# Why are there strange horizontal lines in raster data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, rasterization

I have a feature class (stored in a file geodatabase) containing information on land use for the Amazon rainforest. It is very detailed and looks like this

[image]

I need to convert this shapefile to a raster to combine it with other rasters using the Combine tool (I've encountered too many problems using spatial join with such detailed data). The conversion to raster yields the following image

[image]

Any idea why the raster image have horizontal lines on them? The horizontal lines seem to contain information (i.e. they are not null values)

Comment: maybe more of a workaround than an answer, but what happens if you dissolve before you convert to raster? I notice what look like many small tiles containing the same class; many of the resulting errors seem to originate from those tile boundaries

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It makes a lot of sense to use the dissolve tool. Using it reduced the number of polygons from almost 2 million to just 46!

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this with detailed vector data. Basically it leaks out.
Polygons with duplicate vertices. Or even self intersecting. When I would use a fill or especially a hatch fill it would 'leak' out.
Try running the repair geometry (i assume shape file data type) also as suggested the dissolve and or simplify would be worth looking at the results

Comment: Thanks! I've tried running the repair geometry tool, but it always fails (or gets stuck). Using the Dissolve tool is a great idea.

Comment: with 2 million rows It would probably take a day or 2 to work through dissolve.

Comment: I had this issue too and Repair Geometry fixed it up right away!

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by invalid geometries. 
Easiest solution is to make a 0.001 meters buffer on your geometries, then run vector to raster again.

Answer (score -2):

Check processing environment, when converting feature to raster. That is the issue

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.